# Борьба с майкрософт, или как писать кросс-платформенный код под linux и windows

Tags: linux, windows, visual-c++, gcc

В общем дело обстоит так, я пишу библиотеку кросс-платформенную под пока 2 платформы.

Пишу я код, и как помню, что в заголовочном файле `stddef.h` должен быть определен тип `size_t`. Я включаю этот заголовочный файл, на что мне компилятор от майкрософт говорит, что такого типа там нет. Ну я же не дурак, и помню что еще он определен в файле `stdint.h`, я подключаю его, и вроде бы все хорошо.

Клонирую свой репозиторий написанный под Windows, пытаюсь его собрать при помощи GCC,　на что получаю моментальную ошибку о том что тип `size_t` определен в заголовочном файле `stddef.h` и предлагает его подключить, тут то у меня и пригорело от того, что либо майкрософт забивают на си стандарт или делают его реализацию так, как им захочется.

[`stddef.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stddef.h)

Хочу узнать как с этим бороться или придется с этим жить и подстраивать проекты так, чтобы на одной платформе были одни заголовки включены, а на других другие?

Comment: самое простое - ifdef и под разные платформы выбирать свои файлы. Если проект чуточку большой - можно платформенно зависимые штуки вынести в отдельный хедер (или несколько под разные платформы). Если проект ещё больше - использовать стандартные инструменты типа autotools или подобные, которые умеют такое сами сделать.

Comment: Если речь про Си, то Microsoft очень старый стандарт использует в своих компиляторах. Если хотите кросс-платформенный код, то забейте на компиляторы от Microsoft, используйте Clang / GCC везде.

Comment: Можно также забить на винду, вообще, поскорее отправится на свалку истории

Comment: @avp что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Kotomi, я имею в виду, что пора уже перестать писать для M$

Comment: Звучит примерно так: "Мы техники и инженеры дилерского центра Автоваз дружно отказываемся от поддержки ВАЗов! Автоваз - мастдай!". К чему эти слоганы, если экосистема MS уже сложилась, а люди на ней зарабатывают?

Comment: @avp, пора бы уже перестать писать для Linu%.